# How to start/join microsoft office live meeting on mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office

How can we join/start live meeting on my macbook pro.
I have microsoft office installed. 
Do i need any other software also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use Live Meeting Web Access to join, but not host meetings.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/msonline/archive/2010/05/25/how-to-use-your-mac-with-sharepoint-online-and-live-meeting.aspx

Comment: thanks for quick reply. So https://www323.livemeeting.com/cc/niso/loginPage this is the URL of web based live meeting.

Comment: On live meeting invitation mail i clicked on "join the meeting" and nothing happened. Do i need anything else to install.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked that up on the web. I don't have any experience with Microsoft products on the Mac, so don't know if you need any additional software.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the excellent Adobe Connect web-based screen-share/collaboration tool: truly cross-platform (hell, it supports PS3) and overall a better feature set.

http://www.adobe.com/products/adobeconnect.html

Answer (score 0):

Also note that Microsoft Live Meeting works in Safari but not on Chrome. At least on my MacBookPro and Leopard. In case you have other browser than Safari set as a default browser, you'll need to copy-paste the LiveMeeting link into Safari

Comment: On safari i am getting error "safari can't open the specified address"